# How to overlay country map on Google world map in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, web-mapping, open-source-gis, development

I am creating one map. So I want to overlay country map on Google world map. I am trying with the `OpenLayers.Layer.wfs()` function, but I am not getting perfect solution. If anybody knows the solution please give me reply.

Comment: We probably need to see your code or at least get some more information on what is not working. If you are trying to overlay onto google maps, is your wfs layer in spherical mercator projection?

Comment: Where do you get country data from ? How is the solution not perfect ? Is it working partially or not at all ? Give us details please.

Answer (score 7):

This official example should give you a general idea of how to overlay a WFS on a map using Openlayers: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-states.html

Please provide more information about your problem if this doesn't help.